# CancelEdit() passes control which isn't desired. What else can I do?

Tags: c#, datagridview, sqlconnection

I'm trying to add some bulletproofing in a `DataGridView edit`.

Columns 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 must have values to comply with datatable primary keys as well as SQL table constraints.

If any of the columns are blank I get either an internal exception on datatable primary keys or a SQL Exception on non nullable columns.

In the `LeaveRow` event, if any column values are null I'm calling `CancelUpdate()`. The problem is when `CancelUpdate()` executes, it is passing control to the top of the event and starting over.

1. Is this the correct behavior of `CancelUpdate()`?
2. Given my stated goal, is there another way I can accomplish?

.

```
private void dgvVX130_LeaveRow(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{      
    bool z = true; // <======= CancelUpdate() passes execution to here
    switch (dgvVX130.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.ToString())
    {
        case "0":
            if (dgvVX130.IsCurrentRowDirty && 
                (dgvVX130.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "" || 
                dgvVX130.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "" || 
                dgvVX130.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString() == ""))
            {
                z = false;
                dgvVX130.CancelEdit(); // <=== Passes execution to top of event
                MessageBox.Show("You must have Database, Schema, and TableName " +
                    "defined before leaving row"); // <===== Doesn't get executed
            }
            break;
        case "1":
            // Additional code is irrelevant
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using the RowValidating or CellValidating events instead.

Comment: Please be more specific.  I tried CellValidating before posting the question and got nowhere.  The problem is I need to either cancel proposed edits or return the user to the row to define values for required columns.

Answer (score 1):

Taking LarsTech suggestion I explored and used the RowValidating event.  Was as simple as setting the CancelEventArgs.Cancel property to true.  ( e.Cancel = True; )

```
private void dgvVX130_RowValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
        {
            switch (dgvVX130.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex.ToString())
            {
                case "0":
                    if (dgvVX130.IsCurrentRowDirty && (dgvVX130.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString() == "" 
                        || dgvVX130.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "" 
                        || dgvVX130.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString() == ""))
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("You must have Database, Schema, and TableName defined before leaving row");
                    }
                    break;
                case "1":
                    if (dgvVX130.IsCurrentRowDirty && (dgvVX130.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString() == "" 
                        || dgvVX130.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString() == "" 
                        || dgvVX130.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString() == ""))
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        MessageBox.Show("You must have Database, Schema, and TableName defined before leaving row");
                    }
                    break;
```